# Standard terms other than foo and bar

Tags: standards, sample

When providing example code, "foo" and "bar" are commonly used to represent "arbitrary values", to the point they are almost standard notation.

Are there more "standard" terms for when you want to show more than two arbitrary values?

ie. Is there a standard list of terms whose first two are "foo" and "bar"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Comment: You are looking for [metasyntactic variables](http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable

Comment: Looks like it was commonly known, but I was the only one that decided to make it an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are known as "Metasyntatic variables". I would not consider any of them standard, but Wikipedia offers the following as common in the U.S.:

```
foo
bar
baz
qux
quux
corge
grault
garply
waldo
fred
plugh
xyzzy
thud
```

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable

Personally, I have only seen foo, bar, baz and xyzzy used from the list. The list was cited from [RFC 3092](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3092.html).